# I can't turn on Windows 10 protection

Tags: anti-virus, windows-defender

In June I installed an optimizer called Smart Game booster, when I finished installing it I used it, but later I realized that Windows Defender was disabled.

It is the first time that the Antivirus is deactivated, it had never happened to me, I uninstalled game booster, I went to the control panel to see if I could activate the antivirus from there and it said that it could not.

I went to Windows Services to start it but couldn't either, I currently have Malwarebytes installed until I can turn on Windows Defender again, used the program, it found some viruses and removed them. The only thing I have turned on is Windows Defender Firewall.
CMD doesn't work either.
I hope someone can help me to fix it

---

Spanish Post: el mes de Junio instale un optimizador llamado Smart Game booster, al terminar de instalarlo lo use, pero después me di cuenta de que Windows Defender estaba desactivado.

Es la primera vez que el Antivirus se desactiva, nunca me había pasado, game booster lo desinstale, fui a panel de control para ver si podía activar el antivirus desde ahí y decía que no se podía.

Fui a Servicios de Windows para inicarlo pero tampoco pude, actualmente tengo instalado Malwarebytes hasta que pueda activar Windows Defender nuevamente, use el programa, encontró algunos virus y los eliminó. Lo único que tengo activado es Firewall de Windows Defender.
El CMD tampoco funciona
Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme a solucionarlo

Comment: Lamento que estés experimentando esto. Pero este sitio es principalmente un sitio en inglés. Seguí adelante y usé Google Translate para traducir tu publicación original. Espero que esto ayude. (English: Sorry you are experiencing this. But this site is primarily an English language site. I have gone ahead and used Google Translate to translate your oiriginal post. Hopefully this helps.)

Comment: See https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/15746-fake-game-booster-malware

Comment: Yes, I know. I deleted the program a long time ago from my computer. Que me recomendás?